# Keep an instance of an object for the whole Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rpc, json-rpc

Essentially, I have a simple class that interacts with a local RPC server. Call it `RPC_Class`.
Every user the website will host will make requests that require the rails server to make calls to the RPC client.

This class needs to be instantiated as such

`rpc = RPC_Class.new('localhost:4325')`

And then I make calls to it

`puts rpc.getbalance`

Now, there are three options:

- Create a new instance for every request needed (obviously a bad solution)
- Create a new instance for every user's session
- Create one instance for the whole server

I think option three is the most performative option. Where do I initialize this class such that I can use it throughout the server code?

Comment: Or option 4 - don't optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go with Rails caching for handling this use case. You can cache the response when you make the API call the first time and use the cached response for all the calls you receive after that.
You can write a method like this:

```
def fetch_rpc_balance
  Rails.cache.fetch("rpc_balance", expires_in: 24.hours)
    rpc = RPC_Class.new('localhost:4325')
    puts rpc.getbalance
  end
end
```

Now, if you use the `fetch_rpc_balance` method in your logic, it will make the API call only the first time and return the cached response from second call onwards.

Comment: then you just clear the cache key every time there is an update on balance-
`Rails.cache.delete('rpc_balance')`